# UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cifilter

I'm using CIFilters to convert an image to grayscale and apply some image processing effects. Displaying the output in a UIImageView works; the image displays and has been modified as expected.

However, calling UIImageJPEGRepresentation appears to return no data - every time. It never works.
Calling UIImageJPEGRepresentation using the original color image works fine.

What's going on here? Why might the jpeg conversion fail when displaying the image works fine? No exceptions are thrown (setting an exception breakpoint, it's not hit) and no messages appear in the console.

```
let _cicontext = CIContext(options:nil)

// Set up grayscale and blur filters:
let grayIze = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
let blur = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
grayIze.setValue(0, forKey:kCIInputSaturationKey)
grayIze.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
blur.setValue(4, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

// Go!
let originalImage = CIImage(image: colorImageThatDefinitelyExists)
grayIze.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
blur.setValue(grayIze.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

let output = UIImage(CIImage: blur.outputImage)
let imageData: NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(output, 1.0) // Returns nil!?
```

**Edit: Here is the working code, based on [Arbitur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735571/37168):**

```
// Define an image context at the class level, which will only be initialized once:
static let imageContext = CIContext(options:nil)

// And here's the updated code in a function:
class func convertToGrayscale(image: UIImage)->UIImage?
{
    // Set up grayscale and blur filters:
    let filter1_grayIze = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    let filter2_blur = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    filter1_grayIze.setValue(0, forKey:kCIInputSaturationKey)
    filter1_grayIze.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    filter2_blur.setValue(4, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    // Go!
    let originalImage = CIImage(image: image)
    filter1_grayIze.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter2_blur.setValue(filter1_grayIze.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let outputCIImage = filter2_blur.outputImage

    let temp:CGImageRef = imageContext.createCGImage(outputCIImage, fromRect: outputCIImage.extent())
    let ret = UIImage(CGImage: temp)
    return ret
}

// And finally, the function call:
    if let grayImage = ProfileImage.convertToGrayscale(colorImage)
    {
        let imageData: NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(grayImage, 1.0)
    }
```

Comment: What is `ret` in `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ret, 1.0)` ? I cannot see where it is defined in your code.

Comment: Copy/paste error in the question. Edited.

Comment: Try making it a CGImage first and then UIImage. Ive had that problem with CIImage before.

Comment: That worked! Any idea why? If you put your comment in as an answer I'll Accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the underlying format you are providing to UIImage.  For example, if I set the output settings of AVCaptureStillImageOutput to `imageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]`, I can use create a UIImage directly from the CIImage and use UIImageJPEGRepresentation successfully.  However, if I set the output settings to
            `imageOutput.outputSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]`, then I must convert to an intermediate CGImage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ive had the problem before with CIImage and to work around that I made a CGImage with the CIImage and then a UIImage with the CGImage.

Comment: Suggestion: Your answer could be improved by posting the code needed to accomplish this.

Answer (score 34):

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` seems to use the `CGImage` property of the `UIImage`. Problem is, that when you initialize the `UIImage` with a `CIImage`, that property is `nil`.

My solution was to add following block before the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` call:

**Last update Swift 5.1**

```
if image.cgImage == nil {
    guard 
        let ciImage = image.ciImage, 
        let cgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) 
    else { 
         return nil 
    }

    image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works like a charm. Not sure I ever would have stumbled on the nil CIImage property.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Daniel is working great. Below his answer converted for usage in Swift4.

**Swift4**

```
    if image?.cgImage == nil {
        guard let ciImage = image?.ciImage, let cgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return }

        image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
```