# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value DESPITE checking

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have the following swift 3 code in an xcode 8 project:

```
if pictureImg.image == nil {
  print("image nil")
}

if pictureImg.image != nil {
  print("image not nil")
}

if pictureImg.image != nil {
  imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pictureImg.image!, 0.5)!
}
```

At runtime, I end up with a peculiar result in the console:

```
image not nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

And so it appears that my pictureImg.image is in fact nil *despite* my previous *identical* if statement saying otherwise. Checks to see whether UIImageJPEGRepresentation is nil also results in the same error:

```
if UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pictureImg.img!, 0.5) == nil { *code* }
```

confirming the problem is definitely to do with pictureImg.image, or so it seems.

Is there an immediate/obvious issue with this code or will more information about the project need to be stated?

Comment: Are you checking if `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is returning `nil`?  You're force-unwrapping the return value there.  Also you should be using `if let` statements instead of checking for `nil`.

Comment: Never, ever use ! To unwrap optional sin Swift. There are so many nice ways to do it. This is the smash it with big things approach.

Comment: @Fogmeister, "optional sin Swift"!?!  Now that's a funny typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pictureImg.image!, 0.5)!` returns nil. Check apple documentation. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation

Do something like this:

```
if let image = pictureImg.image {
   if let imageRepresentation = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
     ...
   }
}
```

This way you are not going to have any issues.

Or you can chain them as @Emptyless suggested

```
if let image = pictureImg.image, let imageRepresentation = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Please vote to close the question as a duplicate then: [UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732886/uiimagejpegrepresentation-returns-nil)

Comment: You can chain these in 1 if let statement. If you are only interested in that specific combination I think it looks more neat.

Comment: Works like a charm! Apologies for this question if it's dumb, I'm new to this game, and I'm really thankful you guys can help us idiots!