# UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns nil (on a device - OK on Simulator)

Tags: ios, swift, null, uiimage

I get nil on an iOS device (works ok on Simulator or Playground) when I create create a barcode UIImage with generateBarcode("ABCDEF") and call **UIImageJPEGRepresentation** or **UIImagePNGRepresentation**.

There is clearly something still wrong in the UIImage as the debugger cannot display the UIImage either. The image exists, the cgImage property is set but UIImageJPEGRepresentation doesn't like it.

I have tried to solve it as per: [UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732886/uiimagejpegrepresentation-returns-nil)

```
class func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {  
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)  

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let ciImage = filter.outputImage {  
            if let cgImange = convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: ciImage) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgImange)
            }
        }  
    }  
    return nil  
} 

class func convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImage.extent) {
        return cgImage
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: What type of device u're using?

Comment: Using a fairly recent 10.5" iPad (MPHJ2B/A), iOS 10.3.3

Comment: As described in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation in **Returned value** section:
A data object containing the JPEG data, or nil if there was a problem generating the data. This function may return nil if the image has no data or if the underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported bitmap format._
So, I think, in your case, you have problems with generating data. Maybe you don't have memory on your device or something. Possible solution reload your device and delete and reinstall you app.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try a different device to eliminate the new iPad but I suspect as you say the likely culprit is the CIFilter function.

Comment: So, did you resolve this issue?Or will it work correctly on another device?

Comment: No it didn't. I've built a test harness and it exhibits the same behaviour, i.e. on either iPad UIImageJPEGRepresentation cannot process a barcode UIImage created with CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator").

Comment: It is fixed in iOS11.

Comment: but not fixed on iOS 9 and 10, right?