# Using Core Image Filters in ios - cannot save resulting image - swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I am applying a number of core image filters to an image that I have captured. The problem that I am facing is that once I have applied the filters and saved the resulting image, I am unable to save it.  I do not get any errors in my code but when I go to retrieve the image the application is unable to locate it. It says that the file does not exist. I suspect I may have used the filters incorrectly some how.

```
 // PROCESS IMAGE TO MAKE IT LOOK 'SCANNED'
    guard let scannedImage = self.processImage(image: image)else{
        print("failed to process image")
        return
    }

    // SAVE SCANNED IMAGE TO LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
    self.saveImageToLocalFile(image: scannedImage) // PROBELM HERE.



 // PROCESS IMAGE
func processImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    guard let ciimage = CIImage.init(image: image) else{return nil}

    // APPLY FILTERS

    guard let shadowCimage = shadow(inputImage: ciimage) else{return nil}
    guard let colorControlCimage = colorControl(input: shadowCimage, contrast: 4.0, saturation: 0.3, brightness: 0.3) else{return nil}
    guard let sharpenCimage = sharpen(inputImage: colorControlCimage, inputRadius: 2.5, inputIntensity: 1.0) else {return nil}
    guard let sharpIntensity = sharpenLumin(inputImg: sharpenCimage, inputSharpness: 0.2) else{return nil}

    print("processImage END")
    return UIImage.init(ciImage: sharpIntensity)

}

 // FILTER 'CIColorControls'
func colorControl(input: CIImage, contrast: Float, saturation: Float, brightness: Float) -> CIImage? {

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    filter?.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(contrast, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
    filter?.setValue(saturation, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
    filter?.setValue(brightness, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)

    return filter?.outputImage
}


// FILTER 'CIUnsharpMask'
func sharpen(inputImage: CIImage, inputRadius: Float, inputIntensity: Float) -> CIImage? {

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIUnsharpMask")
    filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    //filter?.setDefaults()

    filter?.setValue(inputRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    filter?.setValue(inputIntensity, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

    return filter?.outputImage
}




// FILTER 'CIHighlightShadowAdjust'
func shadow(inputImage: CIImage) -> CIImage? {

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIHighlightShadowAdjust")
    filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setDefaults()
    return filter?.outputImage
}


// FILTER 'CISharpenLuminance'
func sharpenLumin(inputImg: CIImage, inputSharpness: Float) -> CIImage? {

    let filter = CIFilter.init(name: "CISharpenLuminance")
    filter?.setValue(inputImg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(inputSharpness, forKey: kCIInputSharpnessKey)
    return filter?.outputImage
}






 // SAVE UIIMAGE TO LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
func saveImageToLocalFile(image: UIImage) -> Void {

    // CREATE URL - SAVE TO PATH
    let imageURL = createPhotoURL() // CORRECT FULL LENGTH URL FOR FILE UPLAOD
    print("IMAGE SAVED TO URL: \(imageURL)")
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    do{

        try imageData?.write(to: imageURL)
        self.scannedImageURL = imageURL

    }catch{
        print("error writing img to local dir")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest rendering what you think is the `UIImage` in a `UIImageView` - if it looks like what you expect, then you know the issue is with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. If it doesn't, then you know the issue is happening before that. Also, I'm having a hard time reading through your code to determine exactly where things would crash if in fact your final output for `processImage` is in fact `nil`. Any idea where?

Comment: @dean _Swift Coding Tip:_ Explicit inclusion of `init` isn't required - so use `CIImage(image:` rather than `CIImage.init(image:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `imageData` is `nil`, because of how you are creating the `UIImage`.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40397318/7014451), you have a `nil` in the `UIImage.cgImage` property, which `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` uses. Here's the code you need to use:

```
func saveImageToLocalFile(image: UIImage) -> Void {
    let imageURL = createPhotoURL()
    var uiImage = image
    if image.cgImage == nil {
        guard let ciImage = image.ciImage, let cgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return }
        uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiImage, 1.0) {
        do {
            try imageData?.write(to: imageURL)
            self.scannedImageURL = imageURL
        } catch {
            print("error writing img to local dir")
        }
    } else {
            print("could not create JPEG image")
    }
}
```